# How to generate same hash for simillar text (Semantic similarity)?

Tags: java, mysql, text, similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a table in my database like this :

| id | article_title | signature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title of article 1 | signatureX |
| .. | ... | ... |
| n | Title of article n | signatureY |

Is there any algorithm to generate the same "signature" for similar titles. So when I want to get all the similar titles I will just get the articles that have the same signature.

Example of similar titles :

"COVID-19 is an emerging, rapidly evolving situation."

"COVID-19 is an emerging, evolving situation."

ps: I have tested MD5 after removing stop words from the title, but it is not efficient.

Comment: Are you looking for [SOUNDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) ?

Comment: SOUNDEX would not work given the example. You're ultimately trying to solve a problem as complex as semantic tagging. It is far beyond solvable with a hashing function.

Comment: OK, the question should explain more about what is considered 'similar'...

Comment: Is "COVID is an emerging, evolving situation." the same? Is "COVID19 is a compilcated situation."? Is ...? This is not really solvable. What you may be looking for is something like elastic search that does full text index the article_title, which you can then query and get results ranked based on the quality of their match. But hashing is completely ill-suited for this.

Comment: I am very bad about terms, can you explain (in English) what "(Semantic similarity)" means? 

Comment: @Luuk https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity - not "how similar is the string" but "how similar is what the string *means*".

Comment: Thank you guys, @luk2302 I will read about elastic search and I will check if it is suitable for my need because in the project I have massive data (+2M entries)

Comment: That is a negligible amount of data ;) no problem for es. but go ahead and check out if it actually helps you :)

Comment: I’m pretty convinced that what you meant to ask is not possible. Sorry.

Comment: @OleV.V. I am convinced too :). I am just asking where to start my search about other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution to find similarity, (not "semantic similarity"!):

Lets assume we have the table `covid` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `covid` (
  `c` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `covid` VALUES 
   ('COVID-19 is an emerging, rapidly evolving situation.',1),
   ('COVID-19 is an emerging, evolving situation.',2);
```

When doing this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
     SELECT 
        1 as i
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
        i+1 
     FROM cte 
     WHERE i<10)
SELECT w, count(*), GROUP_CONCAT(id)  line
FROM (
   SELECT 
      id, split(x.c,',',i) as w
   FROM 
      (select id, replace(c,' ',',') as c from covid) x,
      cte) w1
WHERE NOT w is NULL and w<>''
GROUP BY w
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

you should get a result like this:

```
+------------+----------+------+
| w          | count(*) | line |
+------------+----------+------+
| an         |        2 | 1,2  |
| COVID-19   |        2 | 1,2  |
| emerging   |        2 | 1,2  |
| evolving   |        2 | 2,1  |
| is         |        2 | 1,2  |
| situation. |        2 | 2,1  |
| rapidly    |        1 | 1    |
+------------+----------+------+
```

Based on the `count`, you now know which `line`s in the table `covid` have the same words.

If you want to expand this to 'similary' you should probably:

- Skip words with less than x characters (i.e. less then 3)
- Do something about the '.' in 'situation.' (and other punctuation characters)

So, it is indeed a long way to have 'symantic similarity'.